# php ftp slow on ec2

Tags: php, ftp, amazon-ec2

We've set up an EC2 instance to take backups of our website using php's FTP library, but it's extremely slow.

Used to take 10-15 seconds to backup about 25MB on our old box, now it's taking 7 minutes on EC2.

Would passive FTP have anything to do with it?

The ports for passive have been set up in vsftpd.conf as 1024-1048, the ports have been opened in the security group.

config stuff:

```
pasv_enabled=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
pasv_address="Public dns/IP of the instance"
```

The instance was a large one, I so know it has the juice...

So basically, it works but it's sooo slow. I've tried it on a bunch of different instance sizes, and the transfer time is always the same. 23.5MB takes about 7:54 minutes to transfer.

I know using php's ftp library isnt the best, and maybe a different solution is required, but it needs to be server to server without touching a pc.

traceroute:

```
1  ip-10-212-180-3.ec2.internal (10.212.180.3)  0.377 ms  0.580 ms  0.603 ms
 2  ip-10-1-44-9.ec2.internal (10.1.44.9)  0.512 ms  0.494 ms  0.463 ms
 3  ip-10-1-34-72.ec2.internal (10.1.34.72)  0.461 ms  0.449 ms ip-10-1-34-8.ec2.internal (10.1.34.8)  2.975 ms
 4  100.64.20.73 (100.64.20.73)  0.489 ms 100.64.20.75 (100.64.20.75)  0.438 ms 100.64.20.235 (100.64.20.235)  0.512 ms
 5  216.182.224.92 (216.182.224.92)  2.354 ms 216.182.224.218 (216.182.224.218)  1.642 ms 216.182.224.228 (216.182.224.228)  1.792 ms
 6  100.64.2.173 (100.64.2.173)  1.917 ms 100.64.2.125 (100.64.2.125)  1.176 ms 100.64.2.107 (100.64.2.107)  1.508 ms
 7  100.64.0.144 (100.64.0.144)  1.494 ms 100.64.0.172 (100.64.0.172)  1.437 ms 100.64.0.6 (100.64.0.6)  1.656 ms
 8  100.64.16.155 (100.64.16.155)  0.610 ms 100.64.16.91 (100.64.16.91)  39.310 ms 100.64.16.75 (100.64.16.75)  0.654 ms
 9  72.21.220.241 (72.21.220.241)  0.726 ms 205.251.245.54 (205.251.245.54)  1.587 ms 72.21.220.241 (72.21.220.241)  0.448 ms
10  72.21.220.46 (72.21.220.46)  1.550 ms 205.251.245.54 (205.251.245.54)  11.483 ms  1.512 ms
11  equinix.dc2.ash.oneandone.net (206.126.236.200)  3.265 ms 72.21.220.54 (72.21.220.54)  1.441 ms  1.530 ms
12  equinix.dc2.ash.oneandone.net (206.126.236.200)  9.687 ms  10.203 ms te-2-2.bb-c.ms.mkc.us.oneandone.net (74.208.6.101)  46.610 ms
13  te-2-2.bb-c.ms.mkc.us.oneandone.net (74.208.6.101)  46.525 ms  46.139 ms  46.430 ms
14  ae-10.bb-c.slr.lxa.us.oneandone.net (74.208.6.106)  46.924 ms ae-11.gw-distp-a.slr.lxa.oneandone.net (74.208.1.117)  46.918 ms  47.368 ms
15  ae-11.gw-distp-a.slr.lxa.oneandone.net (74.208.1.117)  47.362 ms ae-1.gw-prtr-r5-a.slr.lxa.oneandone.net (74.208.1.167)  47.142 ms ae-10.gw-distp-a.slr.lxa.oneandone.net (74.208.1.101)  47.266 ms
16  * * ae-1.gw-prtr-r5-a.slr.lxa.oneandone.net (74.208.1.167)  47.183 ms
17  u15393060.onlinehome-server.com (74.208.218.40)  46.636 ms  47.613 ms  47.321 ms
```

Comment: Where are you backing up from? What data center are you backing up to? Network bandwidth and latency have the largest effect on what you are experiencing, you need to provide more information about that to make a judgement on what can be done to improve your situation.

Comment: Its going to an east data center, from a 1and1 VPS in Chicago. However I don't think that's the issue. We had this running on a very small VPS from mediatemple, and it transfered 1.7GB in just over a minute from a server on the west coast to the Chicago VPS.

Comment: I would not use php to make backups but use something like rsync if you have shell access on both servers.

Comment: Not an option. Needs to be adhoc. Servers will be added and removed through an interface, some dont belong to us so we may not have access to shell

Comment: @David You are dealing with a different route/network than you had before. Being that this is all in the US, it shouldn't be slow, but its worth checking. Run a traceroute between your server and ec2 instance.

Comment: completed in 48.524 ms. made 30 hops

Comment: @David 30 hops? That seems like alot. Can you tell where the hops are? Do you any of them seem to be going though places that don't make sense? Like Chicago to LA then to US East (which is in Virginia)

Comment: Doesn't seem like a crazy route to me. Starts at amazon, goes through a few backbones, then ends up at 1and1 where it does 5 more hops. I'll put the traceroute in the OP

Comment: While I can't identify the locations of all IP addresses, it seems fairly direct. Latency does jump a bit into 1&1 but not to a level that would be problematic. At this point I would try to eliminate each factor to narrow down the problem. Try uploading a file manually via command line. Try with both ftp and scp.

Comment: Both work as expected, and copied over fast. I'm thinking it has something to do with either passive being on, or the vsftpd config being wrong.

Comment: @David Were you ever able to find a solution for this?  I have a similar issue.

Comment: @tjfo I was, but I'm not sure if your set up the same. The problem wasn't that it was "slow" per the network, but the way we were doing it was. The connections to the FTP was being limited due to the max open connections. The server was going so fast that it would max them out, then wait for connections to end/drop. The wait was usually around 1 or 2 seconds, but when your transferring individual files each with it's own connection, it adds up. The fix was simple, we zipped the whole thing into a file, then transferred just that instead of a million files. Transfer speeds were around 25Mb/sec.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  As it turns out, I had the security group configured incorrectly for the FTP server host IP. Doh!